# Decimals with no value defined don`t get the zeros

Tags: java, teechart

I have a pie graphic and the teechart don`t put the decimals when an integer is put.
Example: If one piece of the pie has the value "2", the legend shows "2" instead "2,00" since the grafic has another pieces with decimals (eg: 3,55).
And other pieces also has the values "12,5" instead of "12,50". Even if i set the serie valueFormat to "#.##" it don't work.

Here's the image (TeeChart java v3):
[image: TeeChart Java v3 decimals example]

Comment: Are you calling `setValue()` to update the field?

Comment: Did you try to explicitely input `2,00` ?

Comment: The solution is above. Thank you guys for taking a few time to look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even if i set the serie valueFormat to "#.##" it doesnt work.

`#` is sometimes just used as an optional placeholder and if the places are not required, i.e. they would be zero, then they are not used. Try `#.00`

Comment: Bingo! That's it! I've put #.00 and it works like a charm.
Thanks @weston.